# My User has disappeared but files still there in "maintenance" programs

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

Just about to upload pics from phone to PC. Go to Pictures and get folder is empty. Long story short all my data folders *appear* empty. But if I use Folder Size or the excellent "Everything" all the files are there. If I copy the path to Explorer I go back to and empty folders.

If I go to `C:\Users\` the usual entry `C:\Users\Steve` is missing. (C: is a SSD.)

I have since discovered that nothing happens when I right click on the Windows icon (I was trying to get to Control Panel). If I left click on the Windows logo when I get inside I am similarly limited. EG Control Panel does appear but I cannot click on it.

Movies I have downloaded onto my internal HDD `D:` drive are fine, as are my BBC downloads for iPlayer stored on D.

**CORRECTION:** BBC programs and now stored on C: (they were stored on D: until the last update). The recordings are stored in the Video directory of user `steve` and found fine.

It is as if I have lost my user identity. I am tempted to power down and on again but ...

Ran AVG nothing found.

I am flummoxed. Any thoughts gratefully appreciated.
Steve

PS Forgot to say that my quite hefty `xampp` directory etc are all there on `D:` as per normal. EDIT: Sorry meant `C:` of course.

PPS I tried a right click on a directory to use Zip but I get nothing on the context menu.

PPPS Used WinRAR to compress files (as a recovery safety net) and they appearing the correct directories while the directories and NOT visible from higher folders nor are lower folders visible. IE the folder can be accessed by specifying the full path in Explorer only.

Comment: Are you sure you are not logged into a temporary profile?

Comment: @Ramhound Well first I'm an idiot - lots of files had been set to hidden and now everything seems to be fine. But something was up as I could not right click on Window logo and all MY Desktop icons were gone etc etc. Not sure what it was but Windows has cured itself. One question: Do u think I should leave this post in case an idiot like me comes along (in which case I will edit it into an answer) or delete it in case I get marked down? ATB and thanks Steve

Comment: This question has zero votes.  All questions asked are factored into your ability to ask new questions.  If you have asked questions that were poorly received in the past, you should improve this question, then simply answer the question.  What you should not do is, answer your question, within the question body.  That will attract downvotes.